# How to find the second element in a stream satisfying some condition?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to display the second element of the stream for which the name starts with 's'.

I tried:

```
employees.stream()
         .filter(e -> e.getName().charAt(0) == 's')
         .findAny()
         .ifPresent(e -> System.out.println("Employee : " + e));
```

However, when I use `findAny()`, it returns the first element in the stream (same as `findFirst()`) and I want the second one.

Comment: I'd rather write e.getName().startsWith("s").. but that's me..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can skip the first match by adding `skip(1)` after the filter:

```
employees.stream()
         .filter(e -> e.getName().charAt(0) == 's')
         .skip(1)
         .findAny()
         .ifPresent(e -> System.out.println("Employee : " + e));
```

Comment: +1. I would've added to preferably use findFirst if working with single threaded stream, as there's no need to use findAny here